# How can I fix my Castle Windsor registration?

Tags: autofac, castle-windsor

I've tried so hard to make this work, but when I try to resolve `IConfigReader` from the container it says that I haven't registered any components.  I've read through it over and over again. Baffled!

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterType<ConsoleLogger>().As<ILogger>();
var output = new StringWriter();
builder.RegisterInstance(output).As<TextWriter>();
builder.Register(c => new ConfigReader("mysection")).As<IConfigReader>();
var container = builder.Build();

using(var scope = container.BeginLifetimeScope())
{
   var reader = container.Resolve<IConfigReader>();
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and provide [mcve]

Comment: This looks like an Autofac registration. But now that someone has asked a question tagged `castle-windsor` it's possible to commit for the proposed `castle-windsor` [documentation category](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/castle-windsor/commit).

Comment: Really bad question title.